# How can I make Requests wait for a 302 redirection to finish in Python?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-status-code-302

I am new to web scraping, and I'm trying to get some data from a site, but there is a waiting queue when you enter it (maybe ~15 seconds when I try in a real browser), which is another url.

When using Requests in Python, I am never getting redirected to the real url, even if it is a 302 redirect (which should be temporary).

Using this code :

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(store, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.history)
```

I get :

```
200
[<Response [302]>]
```

If I put `allow_redirects=False`, I just get an empty page.
How can I wait for the waiting queue to finish, and redirect me to the real site, before using bs4 to fetch the data I want ?

I tried to insert that in a loop to check for `r.url` every x seconds but it never changes. Also tried to `get` every x seconds but same result.

Comment: Have you tried `s.get(store, allow_redirects=True, timeout=None)`?

Comment: I just did, it didn't change anything, still blocked in waiting queue url

Comment: Use tcpdump to find out what your browser does differently

Comment: Sorry I just added the headers parameter that I was already using here, isn't the `get` supposed to follow what my browser does with that ?

Comment: pls check the output of：
`r = s.get(store, allow_redirects=False)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)`

Comment: It only prints that : `<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="the address of the waiting queue">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems , the response contains a javascript that do the redirect thing...
so  may be you need read the redirect url from that r.text,

Comment: r.text only contains the url of the waiting queue like that : `<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body> <h2>Object moved to <a href="the address of the waiting queue">here</a>.</h2> </body></html>`

Comment: so ，can you try，  get this “the address” from a tag (with BeautifulSoup), then request that